# Dummy variables questions : how to create a dummy-variable dataset that has repeated IDs?

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, dummy-variable

I have this df

```
df = data.frame(ID = rep(1:3,each=5),
                group = c('A','B','A','A','C','B','D','C','B','A','A','B','B','A','C') )
```

and I wish to create dummy variables columns A,B,C and D with the result that if there is the value A, we make the value 1 eventhough there are many values A for the ID number 1.

The desired output is as follows

```
  ID A B C D
1  1 1 1 1 0
2  2 1 1 1 1
3  3 1 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
+(as.data.frame.matrix(table(df)) > 0)

#  A B C D
#1 1 1 1 0
#2 1 1 1 1
#3 1 1 1 0
```

Or with `pivot_wider`:

```r
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = "group", values_from = "group", 
                   values_fn = ~ +(length(.x) > 0), values_fill = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(unique(df)), ID ~ group, length)
```

-output

```
   ID A B C D
1:  1 1 1 1 0
2:  2 1 1 1 1
3:  3 1 1 1 0
```